# Prettier Typescript Constructor Parentheses

Tags: typescript, prettier

I have a project with prettier installed. And it always reformats the following code:

```
constructor(public url: string) {
}
```

To:

```
constructor(public url: string) {}
```

Is there an option to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Prettier is an opinionated formatter so has limited options. The idea is to stop people worrying about irrelevant formatting details so they can spend their time doing something more useful.